# scrapy passing arguments from a function to another

Tags: python, scrapy

I have `while` loop inside the `parse_page` function and I don't want to brake it until it reaches it's limit.

I want to pass 3 arguments from the function `parse_page` to `description` and then go to `description_item`.

And after it parses the function `description_item` I want it to return to the `while` loop inside the `parse_page` function.

This is part of my code:

```
def parse_page(self, response):
    item = TestItem()

    ... # more code here

    while i <= len(response.xpath("//script[2]//text()").extract_first()):
        # parsing url
        parsed = urlparse.urlparse(url)
        tranz_type = urlparse.parse_qs(parsed.query)['tranz']
        categ_type = urlparse.parse_qs(parsed.query)['categ']

        id = js2xml.jsonlike.make_dict(jstree.xpath("//var[@name='ANUNTURI']//property[@name='ID']")[i])
        item['url'] = url

        item['id'] = id[1]
        item['tranz_type'] = tranz_type
        item['categ_type'] = categ_type
        i += 1

        request = Request(response, callback=self.description)
        request.meta['id'] = id
        request.meta['tranz_type'] = tranz_type
        request.meta['categ_type'] = categ_type

        #yield item
        return request


def description(self, response):

    id =response.meta.get('id')
    tranz_type =response.meta.get('tranz_type')
    categ_type =response.meta.get('categ_type')

    data = {'id_anunt': id, 'tranz': tranz_type, 'categ': categ_type, 'mc': '1', 'id_cautare': '0'}

    print data

    req = FormRequest.from_response(response, url="http://map.imobiliare.ro/map/serv/detalii", formdata=data,
                                    callback=self.description_items)

    yield req

def description_item(self, response):

    item = TestItem()

    item['link'] = json.loads(response.body).get('link')

    yield item
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a dict to parameter [meta](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.meta) when initializing `Request`:

> meta (dict) – the initial values for the Request.meta attribute. If
>   given, the dict passed in this parameter will be shallow copied.

Then you can access it by `response.meta`.